# How to store a 2D array with TypeORM (and PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, multidimensional-array, typeorm

I would like to store a structure like this one:

```
class MyEntity {
  items: string[][];
}
```

How can I decorate this column to store an array of array of the same type?

There could be 50 to 500 `items` per `MyEntity`. Also there is no big need for searching on this column apart from serving the data as part of `MyEntity`.

If a `string[][]` can't be stored, what's the best way to store this with TypeORM and PostgreSQL?

Thank you,

Comment: why not save the data normalized withoit any arrays, depending whar you want, it would be easier to handle

Comment: yes you're right, without much need to search on this data I went for an array of text marshalling data before saving it.

Comment: you can always produce array when you select the data